# Transition in Navbar when Scroll Down

Tags: javascript, html, css

My navbar color will be change when I scroll down. The color is changing. But there is no transition effects. How to give a transition for this. Here is my Code..

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(this).scrollTop() > 0)
{
    $('.navbar-trans').addClass('afterscroll');
} else
{
    $('.navbar-trans').removeClass('afterscroll');
}
```

});

This is my script code. and my css is,

```
.navbar.navbar-trans.afterscroll { background-color:#1ba4df; }
```

How to give an animation to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this rule in your css file. It will work for you, because here the `transition` property is set to all changes...

```
.navbar-trans {transition: all 0.3s ease; /* other css rules here */}
```

Read more about transition property [here...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property)

Comment: Welcome Melbin..! Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thats it... Try this dude....

```css
.navbar.navbar-trans.afterscroll { 
background-color:#1ba4df; 
Transition:0.3s all linear;
}
```