# Navbar change color javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

as other here I try to modify the navbar during scrolling down. I read this question:

[Changing nav-bar color after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706003/changing-nav-bar-color-after-scrolling)

[Transition in Navbar when Scroll Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434935/transition-in-navbar-when-scroll-down)

[Bootstrap navbar change color to the scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44214238/bootstrap-navbar-change-color-to-the-scroll)

I can't make it work on my website, I don't understand the issue:

HTML:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar justify-content-center navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-custom">
    <!-- Menu Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav" >
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
            <!-- Wanted Logo -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/logo-light.png" alt="wanted_logo" style="width: 3vw;">
        </a>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!-- End Navbar -->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.navbar-custom ul li{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 34px;

}

.navbar-custom img{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}

.navbar-custom.scrolled {
    background-color: red !important;
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}
```

JS:

```
<script>$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $(".navbar-custom");
    $nav.toggleClass("scrolled", $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
  });
});
</script>
```

From my understanding when scrolling down further than the size of the navbar it should change color.

I though it could be a issue because the height of the navbar is not explicitly defined here so I tried adding:

CSS

```
.navbar-custom{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    height: 100px;
}
```

It still didn't work, so I tried also to use another version of the JS proposed here:[Changing nav-bar color after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706003/changing-nav-bar-color-after-scrolling)

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
          $(".navbar-custom").css("background-color", "#f8f8f8");
        } else {
          $(".navbar-custom").css("background-color", "blue");
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Same result nothing changes.

I am new using JS what doesn't work here ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using inconsistent scrolling. You have

```
$(window).scroll(function() {...});
```

However you're checking it with

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {...}
```

And you also have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {...});
```

Make these all either `$(window)` or `$(document)`, and it will work.

Comment: But then why this doesn't work:

<script>$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $(".navbar-custom");
    $nav.toggleClass("scrolled", $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
  });
});
</script>

Comment: Because you are checking different things to what your functions are focused on.

Comment: Hum.. I don't fully understand. And I tried to change all the $(document) for $(window) it didn't work then I change to all $(document) and it didn't work either :/
By the way I don't use the 2 scripts at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made it work using this (as part of the w3 back-to-top button tutorial):

JS:

```
<script>
    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

    function scrollFunction() {
        var $nav = $(".navbar-custom");

    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        $nav.toggleClass("scrolled", $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
    }
    }
</script>
```

Link to the w3school back to top button: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp

Thank you